# Mac App won't run outside Xcode, Library missing? Using Library ORSSerial

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, orsserialport

My app builds with no errors or warnings, and runs fine in Xcode 7.2.1. But when I archive it and try to open it outside Xcode the icon briefly flashes and I get this error:

```
Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/ORSSerial.framework/Versions/A/ORSSerial
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/*/Ascel AE20125 Controller.app/Contents/MacOS/Ascel AE20125 Controller
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
    0x7fff626f2000 -     0x7fff62729007  dyld (360.19) <9D05FDF4-65CE-3B53-86D4-ABE1A5BF35F3> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff962e5000 -     0x7fff962e5fff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 22) <0A634D46-B468-3CBC-B2A0-16C381C11BF2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff9c462000 -     0x7fff9c7b6ff7  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1256.1) <66106CC9-9D97-3846-88D8-4BF6BB508296> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
```

How can I compile my App so that it works outside Xcode? This problem occurs when I try to open my compiled .app without the XCODE environment.

The App is made using swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a little on @NickolayOlshevsky's answer, you need to make sure that ORSSerial.framework is being copied into your app's internal Frameworks folder. In the build phases for your project, you should make sure there is a phase (e.g. Embed Frameworks) that copies ORSSerial.framework into the target's Frameworks folder:

[image: Embed Frameworks build phase]

Another way to configure this is to add the framework to the Embedded Binaries section of the General tab of target settings:

[image]

If you open the PacketParsingDemo or RequestResponseDemo example projects that come with ORSSerialPort, you can see this setup configured correctly in those projects.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are copying library to output bundle only for Debug configuration and missing it for Release. Check the project/target settings.